# How do I git push to Azure without deleting existing content

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure website which has a WordPress site and some ASPX pages.

The first time I git push (or github deploy) my ASPX pages, the whole WordPress site is deleted. This was unexpected because I'd tested it out on a temporary website and found that a git push didn't delete content I'd ftp'd. It turns out that subsequent git pushes don't delete. Only the initial git push deletes.

Is there a way to git push to Azure without it deleting any existing content in the wwwroot directory?

Comment: Can you clarify your scenario? You first get WordPress on there via FTP, and then you want to do git publish on top of that? Does your git repo contain WordPress files that you want to overwrite, or only new files?

Comment: I create a new Azure website from the Gallery. I choose WordPress and then have WordPress installed, just like any other item from the Azure gallery. Then I want to push some ASPX pages to wwwroot, so I set up git deployment and git push. Azure then deletes all files from the wwwroot directory on the first git push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is currently by design (see code details [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Core/Deployment/DeploymentManager.cs#L532)). Basically, the initial deployment is always done cleanly. Afterwards, subsequent deployments preserve files that were dynamically added.

One reason we do this is that new 'empty' sites contain a hostingstart.html placeholder file that users would not expect to stay around after pushing with git.

Though I can see your point in this scenario. If I understand correctly, you're basically trying to have two unrelated web apps running in the same site: WordPress from the gallery, and some ASP.NET app you're git pushing. Not a scenario we had foreseen, but we could consider it.

Please open an issue on [github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) to get it on the radar.